# Does/Will autofac's ASP.NET integration support PreInit or Init events?

Tags: asp.net, autofac

I see from poking around in the 1.4.4 source that Autofac's ASP.NET integration (via Autofac.Integration.Web) peforms injection of properties on the `Page` as part of the `HttpContext.PreRequestHandlerExecute` event handling, but that the page's child controls don't get *their* properties injected until `Page.PreLoad`.

What this means, though is that the injected properties of child controls are unavailable for use in the OnInit event handler.

For example, this works fine:

```
HelloWorld.aspx:
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="HelloWorld.aspx.cs" Inherits="HelloWorld" %>
<html>
  <body>
    <asp:Label runat="server" id="lblMsg" OnInit="HandleInit"/>
  </body>
</html>

HelloWorld.aspx.cs:
...
protected void HandleInit()
{
    lblMsg.Text = _msgProvider.GetMessage();
}

public IMsgProvider _msgProvider { private get; set; } // <-- Injected
```

But changing the HelloWorld `Page` to a `UserControl` (.acsx) and putting the UserControl in another page doesn't work because `_msgProvider` isn't injected early enough.

Is there a way to make Autofac inject properties of child controls earlier?  Or is this something that can be addressed in a future build?  Thanks!

Comment: This should probably go into the Autofac issue tracker: http://code.google.com/p/autofac/issues/list

Comment: Added as Issue #203 (http://code.google.com/p/autofac/issues/detail?id=203)

Comment: Any workarounds or patches for this issue now?

Comment: @Stingervz As I noted below, I came up with a patch for 1.4.4, but it had to be backed out. I never resolved this issue in Autofac 1.X, and never revisited the issue with more recent releases (changed projects/jobs/etc.). Is it still an issue with Autofac 3.5?

Answer (score 2):

In the end the patch was not accepted.

I think resolving dependency through a base class is a more stable solution:

http://blog.js-development.com/2011/11/autofac-aspnet-webforms-usercontrol.html

In my website I decided to only use dependency injection through a base class for pages and usercontrols so I also don't have the overhead of trying to do the injection on pages and controls that do not need it.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a small patch to Autofac for this issue.  [See the issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/issues/detail?id=203) at the Google Code project for details.

Comment: As noted in the Autofac issue tracker, the patch had to be backed out. The Autofac maintainer resolved the bug as "WontFix".